# Which method should I use to solve the statistic optimization problem?

Tags: statistics, optimization, numerical-methods, algorithms, expected-value

I am just learning something about numerical optimization. And so far I have got a form to minimize, but I have no idea about how to realize it and which method can be used here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrMMA.png)

where z and q are vectors in R^d.

Because here I have the randomness of the samples as J(z), so I think this may belong to the statistic optimization problem. But how can I do that in practice? Which method or algorithm should I use?